# add specific anchor links a class

Tags: javascript, wordpress, divi

How I can add to my anchor links a class?

My html code looks like this:

```
<div class="et_pb_blurb_content">
  <div class="et_pb_main_blurb_image">
    <a href="video.mp4">
      <span class="et_pb_image_wrap">
        <img loading="lazy" width="128" height="128" src="2021/02/cover.png" alt="" class="et-waypoint et_pb_animation_off wp-image-17" />
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_blurb_container">
    <h4 class="et_pb_module_header">
      <a href="video.mp4">Watch</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

With javascript code I want achieve like this it adds anchor links class:

```
<div class="et_pb_blurb_content">
  <div class="et_pb_main_blurb_image">
    <a href="video.mp4" class="vp-a">
      <span class="et_pb_image_wrap">
        <img loading="lazy" width="128" height="128" src="2021/02/cover.png" alt="" class="et-waypoint et_pb_animation_off wp-image-17" />
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_blurb_container">
    <h4 class="et_pb_module_header">
      <a href="video.mp4" class="vp-a">Watch</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use wordpress divi theme and there is not possible add class to anchor video links

Answer (score 0):

Could use something like below:

```
// grab all the parent items by classname
const linkParents = document.querySelectorAll('.et_pb_module_header');

// iterate over parents
[...linkParents].forEach((parent) => {
  // grab the anchor tag from the parent
  const link = parent.querySelector('a');

  // add your classname to the anchor tag
  link.classList.add('vp-a');
});
```